# how much free disk space require to run Hive query

Tags: hadoop, hive

i run following Hive query

> create table table_llv_N_C as select  table_line_n_passed.chromosome_number,table_line_n_passed.position,table_line_c_passed.id from table_line_n_passed join table_line_c_passed on (table_line_n_passed.chromosome_number=table_line_c_passed.chromosome_number)

and  got following error 
`......
    org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: Hive Runtime Error while processing row (tag=1) {"key":{"joinkey0":"12"},"value":{"_col2":"."},"alias":1} at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.ExecReducer.reduce(ExecReducer.java:258) ... 7 more Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException(java.io.IOException): File /tmp/hive-root/hive_2015-03-09_10-03-59_970_3646456754594156815-1/_task_tmp.-ext-10001/_tmp.000000_0 could only be replicated to 0 nodes instead of minReplication (=1). There are 2 datanode(s) running and no node(s) are excluded in this operation. ......`

The root cause may be lack of disk space in the HDFS cluster. details of disk space are

`hdfs dfs -df -h`

`Filesystem            Size  Used  Available   Use%`

`hdfs://x.y.ab.com:8020 159.7 G 21.9 G 110.7 G  14%`.

table_line_n_passed having 4767409 rows and 1.1 G size.

similarly table_line_c_passed having 4717082 rows and 1.0 G size .

Does Hive really require that much space (more then available free space 110 G ) to process data. how to calculate how much free space require before running query .any way to run query within available free space.

PS: if i used LIMIT 10000 in above query its running fine .

Execution plan

`EXPLAIN create table table_llv_N_C as select table_line_n_passed.chromosome_number,table_line_n_passed.position,table_line_c_passed.id from table_line_n_passed join table_line_c_passed on (table_line_n_passed.chromosome_number=table_line_c_passed.chromosome_number);`

OK

ABSTRACT SYNTAX TREE:

`(TOK_CREATETABLE (TOK_TABNAME table_llv_N_C) TOK_LIKETABLE (TOK_QUERY (TOK_FROM (TOK_JOIN (TOK_TABREF (TOK_TABNAME table_line_n_passed)) (TOK_TABREF (TOK_TABNAME table_line_c_passed)) (= (. (TOK_TABLE_OR_COL table_line_n_passed) chromosome_number) (. (TOK_TABLE_OR_COL table_line_c_passed) chromosome_number)))) (TOK_INSERT (TOK_DESTINATION (TOK_DIR TOK_TMP_FILE)) (TOK_SELECT (TOK_SELEXPR (. (TOK_TABLE_OR_COL table_line_n_passed) chromosome_number)) (TOK_SELEXPR (. (TOK_TABLE_OR_COL table_line_n_passed) position)) (TOK_SELEXPR (. (TOK_TABLE_OR_COL table_line_c_passed) id))))))`

`STAGE DEPENDENCIES:`

`(Stage-1 is a root stage`

`Stage-0 depends on stages: Stage-1`

`Stage-4 depends on stages: Stage-0`

`Stage-2 depends on stages: Stage-4`

> STAGE PLANS:
>     Stage: Stage-1
>       Map Reduce
>         Alias -> Map Operator Tree:
>           table_line_c_passed 
>             TableScan
>               alias: table_line_c_passed
>               Reduce Output Operator
>                 key expressions:
>                       expr: chromosome_number
>                       type: string
>                 sort order: +
>                 Map-reduce partition columns:
>                       expr: chromosome_number
>                       type: string
>                 tag: 1
>                 value expressions:
>                       expr: id
>                       type: string
>           table_line_n_passed 
>             TableScan
>               alias: table_line_n_passed
>               Reduce Output Operator
>                 key expressions:
>                       expr: chromosome_number
>                       type: string
>                 sort order: +
>                 Map-reduce partition columns:
>                       expr: chromosome_number
>                       type: string
>                 tag: 0
>                 value expressions:
>                       expr: chromosome_number
>                       type: string
>                       expr: position
>                       type: int
>         Reduce Operator Tree:
>           Join Operator
>             condition map:
>                  Inner Join 0 to 1
>             condition expressions:
>               0 {VALUE._col0} {VALUE._col1}
>               1 {VALUE._col2}
>             handleSkewJoin: false
>             outputColumnNames: _col0, _col1, _col14
>             Select Operator
>               expressions:
>                     expr: _col0
>                     type: string
>                     expr: _col1
>                     type: int
>                     expr: _col14
>                     type: string
>               outputColumnNames: _col0, _col1, _col2
>               File Output Operator
>                 compressed: false
>                 GlobalTableId: 1
>                 table:
>                     input format: org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextInputFormat
>                     output format: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveIgnoreKeyTextOutputFormat
>                     name: bright.table_llv_N_C
>
> Stage: Stage-0
>       Move Operator
>         files:
>             hdfs directory: true
>             destination: hdfs://cheetah.xxx.yyyy.in:8020/user/hive/warehouse/bright.db/table_llv_n_c
>
> Stage: Stage-4
>         Create Table Operator:
>           Create Table
>             columns: chromosome_number string, position int, id string
>             if not exists: false
>             input format: org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextInputFormat
>             # buckets: -1
>             output format: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.IgnoreKeyTextOutputFormat
>             name: table_llv_N_C
>             isExternal: false
>
> Stage: Stage-2
>       Stats-Aggr Operator

Time taken: 0.146 seconds

Comment: Do you have the execution plan for your query (i.e. the output from `EXPLAIN`)?

Comment: @rchang I have included execution plan  in above post ...

Answer (score 0):

Go to this link : https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/Configuration+Properties

And look for this tag. Or search for memory usage on page to get there easily.

```
hive.map.aggr.hash.force.flush.memory.threshold
```

Also refer to this tag or go to second search for memory usage

```
hive.mapjoin.localtask.max.memory.usage
```

Comment: Query running 100% for map but hang on  reduce operation when completed 68% ..  after  reaching default value Hive should flush data .. can u tell what property and value i need to set to run above query .

Comment: Try chang value of this hive.mapjoin.localtask.max.memory.usage. It's default value is 0.90. Also try with change value of hive.mapjoin.followby.gby.localtask.max.memory.usage. Its default value is 0.55. If both of above did not work change the value of hive.mapjoin.check.memory.rows. It's default value is 100000. That's why you don't get exception when you have restrict query under this number.